# Get Random entry with luck rate

Tags: mysql

I am looking for a solution to grab one or more entries with a luck rate. I will try to explain it.

I have a Table which looks like:

```
+-------------------+---------------------+
| Username(varchar) | Subscriber(boolean) |
+-------------------+---------------------+
| Tobi              |                   1 |
| Maik              |                   0 |
| Jelly             |                   0 |
| Arthur            |                   1 |
+-------------------+---------------------+
```

For example i say the luck rate is 3, so the people with the value 1 in subscriber should be picked 3 times higher than someone with the 0 inside.

Comment: ty Gordon for the format help, tried it but failed. So I have declare it as code :)

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND() * IF(Subscriber, 3, 1) DESC LIMIT 1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to choose one row, with "1" being X-times more likely than "0".

The following may be close enough to what you want:

```
select t.*
from table t
order by rand() * (case when Subscriber = 0 then 1 else luckrate end) DESC
limit 1;
```

However, the proportion is not exactly `luckrate`.  This may suffice for your purposes.

EDIT:

The correct formula would appear to be:

```
order by rand() * (case when Subscriber = 0 then 1 else (1 + luckrate)/2.0 end) DESC
```

So, for "3", the factor is 2.  This formula works for `luckrate` >= 1.  It clearly doesn't work for 0.

Here is the logic behind the formula.  I find it easier to calculate the "luckrate" for a given proportion.  So, say the proportion is 10.  That means that we are comparing two uniform random distributions, one goes from 0 to 1 and the other from 0 to 10.  The question is:  how often does the second one "win"?  This is the "luckrate".

Well, when the second one is greater than 1, it always wins.  That occurs 9/10 of the time.  The rest of the time, it wins half the time (that is, 10% of the time there are two uniform distributions between 0 and 1).  So, the overall probability of winning is 90% + 5% = 95%.  This, in turn, corresponds to a "luckrate" of 19.

You can work this out for other winning percentages.  You can do the reverse calculation to get the formula above.  However, this logic only works when the second has a range larger than the first (which is okay, based on the question).

EDIT:

To handle `luckrate` less than 1, I think you would do an inversion and apply the factor on the the `0`s.  Something like this:

```
order by rand() * (case when luckrate = 0 then (subscriber <> 0)
                        when luckrate = 1 then 1
                        when luckrate < 1 and subscriber = 1 or
                             luckrate > 1 and subscriber = 0
                        then 1
                        when luckrate < 1 and subscriber = 0
                        then (1 + (1/luckrate)/2.0)
                        when luckrate > 1 and subscriber = 1
                        then (1 + luckrate)/2.0
                   end) DESC
```

Comment: without sort direction the proportions would be actually the opposite: being multiplied by 3 decreases chances to be chosen.

Comment: "So, for "3", the factor is 2." --- I'm not getting it. `1 + 3/2` == 2.5

Comment: @zerkms . . . I added an explanation.

Comment: Yep, I actually realized that short after I put a comment hence removed it :-) Used the same logic to prove it. However, with a factor = 2 in a sample program I always get the 7:3 ratio (7 out of 10 are winners) http://ideone.com/xfSQXr

Comment: @zerms . . . This appears to be rather slow to converge.  I ran examples in Excel with a factor of 2 and over 1,000 rows.  When I run it, I get winning percentages like 26.6%, 26.0%, 23.1%, 26.2%, 25.1%, 25.7%, 27.7%, 24.9%, 24.0%, . . .  These hover around 25% (the expected value in this case) but with a rather wide variation (in my opinion) for 1,145 points.

Comment: In my code I used 100k iterations :-S Keen to share your excel file?

Comment: @zerkms . . . The rand() function in php returns an integer, which very much changes the logic.  The distribution is no longer uniform over the interval.  There is probably a slight adjustment, but we are getting way beyond the scope of this question.  (The suggestion in Stack Overflow is to use `mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax()` for a uniform distribution between 0 and 1.)

Comment: yep, you beat me by seconds writing your comment :-) Using a wider random interval makes it to converge at 3. Thanks :-)

Comment: sorry, seems that i am dumb, i can follow your explanation but i dont get it how to calculate my percentage. Currently there will a luckrate between 0 and 6 in my program. And thank you guys for your help

Comment: in your edit block, is there a then missing? when luckrate > 1 and subscriber = 1 else (1 + luckrate)/2.0